# How to fix the restart of a activity that crashes in Android?

Tags: java, android, loops, android-activity, onclicklistener

I have created programmatically, 5 radio groups with 4 radio buttons each. The answers are a result of a database query. I have added a restart button and a `OnClickListener`. I want when someone clicks the button, to restart my activity. When first time the app starts, it works fine but when i press the button to reload the activity, I get this error: `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4` How is that possible, first time to work perfectly and when reloading the activity to crash? How can I fix this?
Here is my code:

```
answerGroup = new RadioGroup[5];
answer = new RadioButton[4];
int i = 0;
for (Question qn : questions) {
    answerGroup[i] = new RadioGroup(this);
    answerGroup[i].setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
    int j = 0;
    for (Answer an : answers) {
        if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
            answer[j] = new RadioButton(this);
            answer[j].setText(an.getAnswer());
            answerGroup[i].addView(answer[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    linearLayout.addView(answerGroup[i]);
    i++;
}

restartButton = new Button(this);
restartButton.setText(R.string.restartButton);
linearLayout.addView(restartButton);

restartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Intent intent = getIntent(); you need to set the parameters something like

```
Intent intent = getIntent(getApplicationContext(),NameOfYourClass.class)
```

or try to recreate the Activity if you are on SDK 11+ calling

```
super.recreate();
```

But if neither this will work I think you have some error in your tables. Try to use an ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks you but it doesn't work. I get this error: `get intent in activity cannot be applied`. Any other idea?

Comment: How can i use `super.recreate();`? In stead of `startActivity(intent);`?

Comment: Yes just call it in your button

Comment: It doesn't work either. There is no error in the tables because when first time the app starts, it works fine. Only when i try to recreate the activity, the emulator crashed. And yes, i am using `ArrayList`.